# How to create corpus from pandas data frame to operate with NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk

Here is my problem:

1. I have a csv file containing articles data set with columns: ID, CATEGORY, TITLE, BODY.
2. In python, I read the file to a pandas data frame like this:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
   ```
3. Now I need to transform somehow this `df` to get a corpus object, let's call it `my_corpus`. But how exactly I can do it? I assume I need to use:

   ```
   from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedCorpusReader
   my_corpus = some_nltk_function(df) # <- what is the function?
   ```
4. At the end I can use NLTK methods to analyze the corpus. For example:

   ```
   import nltk
   my_corpus.fileids() # <- I expect values from column ID
   my_corpus.categories() # <- I expect values from column CATEGORY
   my_corpus.words(categories='cat_A') # <- I expect values from column TITLE and BODY
   my_corpus.sents(categories=['cat_A', 'cat_B', 'cat_C']) # <- I expect values from column TITLE and BODY
   ```

Please, advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NLTK: How to create a corpus from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232047/nltk-how-to-create-a-corpus-from-csv-file)

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate as the reference does not give me a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need to do 2 things.

First you need to convert each row of your dataframe *df* to corpus files. The following function should do it for you

```
def CreateCorpusFromDataFrame(corpusfolder,df):
    for index, r in df.iterrows():
        id=r['ID']
        title=r['TITLE']
        body=r['BODY']
        category=r['CATEGORY']
        fname=str(category)+'_'+str(id)+'.txt'
        corpusfile=open(corpusfolder+'/'+fname,'a')
        corpusfile.write(str(body) +" " +str(title))
        corpusfile.close()

CreateCorpusFromDataFrame('yourcorpusfolder/',df)
```

Second, you need to read the files from *yourcorpusfolder* and then do the NLTK processing required by you

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
my_corpus=CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('yourcorpusfolder/',
r'.*', cat_pattern=r'(.*)_.*') 
my_corpus.fileids() # <- I expect values from column ID
my_corpus.categories() # <- I expect values from column CATEGORY
my_corpus.words(categories='cat_A') # <- I expect values from column TITLE and BODY
my_corpus.sents(categories=['cat_A', 'cat_B']) # <- I expect values from column TITLE and BODY
```

Some helpful references :

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nltk-users/YFCKjHbpUkY
- [Need to set categorized corpus reader in NLTK and Python, corpus texts in one file, one text per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538853/need-to-set-categorized-corpus-reader-in-nltk-and-python-corpus-texts-in-one-fi/28852326#28852326)

Comment: Thank you for your code. I thought this can be achieved without .txt files generation step to save the disk space as I have couple of thousands of those. Anyhow I have applied the code and it works for me :)

Comment: I am not sure if you can achieve the operation without writing to disk. If it worked for you, you may mark it as accepted answer. Thanks.