# Text from data frame into a large corpus

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am following a few online tutorials on text processing. One tutorial uses the below code to read in a number of .txt files and put them into one large corpus.

```
corpus_raw = u""
for file_name in file_names:
    with codecs.open(file_name, "r", "utf-8") as file_name:
        corpus_raw += file_name.read()
    print("Document is {0} characters long".format(len(corpus_raw)))
    print()
```

…

Then they go on to process the data:

```
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
raw_sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(corpus_raw)
```

However the text data I have is in a panda dataframe. I have rows which are books and the text for those books are in a cell. I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088978/how-to-create-corpus-from-pandas-data-frame-to-operate-with-nltk) but I cannot seem to get it to work with my data.

My pandas df has an "ID" column called "IDLink" and the text column "text". How can I put all my text data into a large corpus? it Will be to run a Word2Vec model.

EDIT:

This is not working as expected. I thought I would have for each row a list of tokenized words.

```
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
risk['tokenized_documents'] = risk['text'].apply(tokenizer.tokenize)
```

Comment: You mean, you want to have the texts of all rows in one big text, right?

Comment: I think this solves my "issue" `data['text_tokens'] = data.apply(lambda row: 
    nltk.word_tokenize(row['text']), axis=1)` - which gives me tokenised documents for each row of my data but also knowing how to have all text in one large corpus is useful.