# Is there any way to convert python pandas dataframe to NLP corpus or documentation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gensim, corpus

I have 3 columns Smiles, Column, and mobile phase.

I want to convert my dataset to the corpus as a training dataset and apply the Gensim model.

Here is my dataset link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S80I_5zkjJfeTzby7OjIqrs1vMJI6jVo/view?usp=sharing

I have referred this StackOverflow question but can't work

[How to create corpus from pandas data frame to operate with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088978/how-to-create-corpus-from-pandas-data-frame-to-operate-with-nltk/49104725)

Comment: Which gensim model do you want to apply? Why is there a need to create a corpus?

Comment: I wanna try this model doc_to_vec as my experiment
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gensim/gensim_doc2vec_model.htm

Comment: @AlokNayak any suggestion on this kind of dataset where we want to apply gensim model.

Comment: you will need to split text into list of words using just space or any regex before using that in gensim's TaggedDocument & later training doc2vec

Answer (score 0):

Any list of list of words can be converted to list of TaggedDocument & used to train a doc2vec model. OR you can split a dataframe's text column into list of words first and then iterate over output pandas series to create a list of TaggedDocument. Here is example usage for your dataset.Lets assume you load you pandas dataframe as df, then

```
output_ser = df.loc[:, 'Mobile Phase'].str.split(r'[/\s\\]+')
documents = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(output_ser)]
model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=5, window=2, min_count=1, workers=1)
```

Follow this link https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html for usage example

Comment: thanks for your help and support it is working with one column but trying with an entire dataset it is not converted in corpus

Comment: Only text can be used in doc2vec model, If you want to use all columns of pandas dataframe, then you might want to concatenate all columns into one text/string column.

Comment: thanks, @Alok Nayak I have been working on it. will update you soon.