# Can I use Python pandas dataframe to NLP corpus or documentation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gensim, corpus

I wanna try this model doc_to_vec as my experiment

http://tutorialspoint.com/gensim/gensim_doc2vec_model.htm

I want to convert my dataset to the corpus as a training dataset and apply the Gensim model.

Here is my dataset link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S80I_5zkjJfeTzby7OjIqrs1vMJI6jVo/view?usp=sharing

I have referred this StackOverflow question but can't work

[How to create corpus from pandas data frame to operate with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088978/how-to-create-corpus-from-pandas-data-frame-to-operate-with-nltk/49104725)

you can also check my code here google colab

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BmBNrfsxQ0AIJH_1hfMaMAceQLh2Xk7Q?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('ADL_Two_column_MoCo.csv',encoding = 'unicode_escape')
dataset = dataset.dropna()

import gensim
def tagged_document(list_of_list_of_words):
    for i, list_of_words in enumerate(list_of_list_of_words):
        yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(list_of_words, [i])


data = [dataset]
data
data_for_training = list(tagged_document(data))

model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=40, min_count=2, epochs=30)

model.build_vocab(data_for_training)

model.train(data_for_training, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)

len(data_for_training)
1

data_for_training

    [TaggedDocument(words=                                       Smile Canonical              Column  \
 0                         C1=CC=C(C=C1)C2OC(C(O2)CO)CO        CHIRALPAK AD   
 1                     C1=CC=C(C=C1)C(C(C2=CC=CC=C2)O)O        CHIRALPAK AD   
 2                        CC(C1=CC=C(C=C1)C2=CC=CC=C2)O        CHIRALPAK AD   
 5    CC(C1=CC=CC=C1)OC(=O)C2=CC(=CC(=C2)[N+](=O)[O-...        CHIRALPAK AD   
 6       C1=CC=C2C(=C1)C=CC(=C2C3=C(C=CC4=CC=CC=C43)O)O        CHIRALPAK AD   
 ..                                                 ...                 ...   
 839             C1CC(=O)NC(=O)C1N2C(=O)C3=CC=CC=C3C2=O  CHROMEGACHIRAL CCJ   
 840              CC(C1=CC=C(S1)C(=O)C2=CC=CC=C2)C(=O)O  CHROMEGACHIRAL CCJ   
 841  CCC(COC(=O)C1=CC(=C(C(=C1)OC)OC)OC)(C2=CC=CC=C...  CHROMEGACHIRAL CCJ   
 842  CCC(COC(=O)C1=CC(=C(C(=C1)OC)OC)OC)(C2=CC=CC=C...  CHROMEGACHIRAL CCJ   
 843  CCC(COC(=O)C1=CC(=C(C(=C1)OC)OC)OC)(C2=CC=CC=C...  CHROMEGACHIRAL CCJ  




                                      Mobile phase  
 0                                        methanol  
 1                              n-hexane / ethanol  
 2                            water / acetonitrile  
 5                                        methanol  
 6                           n-hexane / 2-propanol  
 ..                                            ...  
 839                                      methanol  
 840  n-hexane / 2-propanol / trifluoroacetic acid  
 841         n-heptane / 2-propanol / diethylamine  
 842                         n-hexane / 2-propanol  
 843                       methanol / diethylamine  
 
 [828 rows x 3 columns], tags=[0])]
```

This is the value which I get.

[image: Training data output]
I'm getting this error

```
 RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-72344a512bb5> in <module>
----> 1 model.train(data_for_training, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py in train(self, documents, corpus_file, total_examples, total_words, epochs, start_alpha, end_alpha, word_count, queue_factor, report_delay, callbacks)
    555             sentences=documents, corpus_file=corpus_file, total_examples=total_examples, total_words=total_words,
    556             epochs=epochs, start_alpha=start_alpha, end_alpha=end_alpha, word_count=word_count,
--> 557             queue_factor=queue_factor, report_delay=report_delay, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
    558 
    559     @classmethod

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py in train(self, sentences, corpus_file, total_examples, total_words, epochs, start_alpha, end_alpha, word_count, queue_factor, report_delay, compute_loss, callbacks, **kwargs)
   1065             total_words=total_words, epochs=epochs, start_alpha=start_alpha, end_alpha=end_alpha, word_count=word_count,
   1066             queue_factor=queue_factor, report_delay=report_delay, compute_loss=compute_loss, callbacks=callbacks,
-> 1067             **kwargs)
   1068 
   1069     def _get_job_params(self, cur_epoch):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py in train(self, data_iterable, corpus_file, epochs, total_examples, total_words, queue_factor, report_delay, callbacks, **kwargs)
    533             epochs=epochs,
    534             total_examples=total_examples,
--> 535             total_words=total_words, **kwargs)
    536 
    537         for callback in self.callbacks:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py in _check_training_sanity(self, epochs, total_examples, total_words, **kwargs)
   1171 
   1172         if not self.wv.vocab:  # should be set by `build_vocab`
-> 1173             raise RuntimeError("you must first build vocabulary before training the model")
   1174         if not len(self.wv.vectors):
   1175             raise RuntimeError("you must initialize vectors before training the model")

RuntimeError: you must first build vocabulary before training the model
```

while I already have made vocabulary but the problem in the data frame.

Comment: That page at 'TutorialsPoint' is an awful starting tutorial - it's not even using logical documents, just run-together words from the bulk `text8` dataset. The tiny demo included w/ Gensim documentation – https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html – is a better starting point. If you have trouble adapting some tutorial to your data, your question should more clearly describe what you tried & what errors/blocking-steps you reached. Simply saying something "can't work" doesn't really show enough detail or effort for answerers to be able to help.

Comment: @gojomo I have edited my question and put my experiment look if you can help...

Comment: You should show the whole error message (with traceback stack) for your error. Also, your code uses a variable `data` that's never defined, so I don't even see how it could reach the `Doc2Vec`-related lines without earlier errors. Are you sure the cod you've shown triggers the error you're reporting?

Comment: @gojomo I have correct that mistake and add my google colab code link where you can find out my logic!

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the `data_for_training` variable to be sure it contains what you expect? If you enable logging at the INFO level, and watching the logging output, does it appear the earlier steps (before `train()`) are working as expected? (This is the kind of error you'd get if your corpus is empty or otherwise defective in ways that make it look empty.)

Comment: I have seen the 'data_for_training' output and it shows the entire data but while applying in the gensim model it doesn't reflect so I am thinking to convert pandas data frame to corpus so the model easily understands.

Comment: Check `len(data_for_training)`, and `data_for_training[0].words` - they may not have what you think. (If they appear to have good data, add code/output showing that to your question.)

Comment: @gojomo I have edit my question with desired  input and output which I got please have a look and suggest me

Answer (score 1):

here is a resource for doc2vec that is very good: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-vectorize-text-in-dataframes-for-nlp-tasks-3-simple-techniques-82925a5600db

```
#1. the text must have spaces before and after the =.
#2. word tokenize the doc generating a list of tokenized docs
#3. doc2bow to vectorize the doc into a list of a list
#4. store the corpus in a dataframe column of type object.

 from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
 from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

 df=pd.read_csv('smile.csv')

 df['corpus']=np.empty
 df['corpus']=df['corpus'].astype(object)
 for key,row in df.iterrows():
     doc=str(row['Smile Canonical'])
     doc=doc.replace('=',' = ')

     tokenized_docs=[word_tokenize(doc.lower())]
     #print(dictionary.token2id)
     dictionary=Dictionary(tokenized_docs)
     corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in tokenized_docs]
     #print(corpus)
     df.loc[key,'corpus']=corpus
```

print("Each document is converted into a bag of words indicating the frequency of each token")
print(df.head())